# Issue passing file based SSH socket with Paramiko

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssh, paramiko

Anyone see any issues with the code below? Specifically with the __connect() method. I'm trying to add the capability to use an existing SSH master control socket to connect and execute commands. If I don't pass in a master control socket and choose to just connect using SSH and authenticate, that part works.

Each time that I pass my master socket in, I'm getting the error: `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`.

The socket name that I'm passing in is `/tmp/ubuntu.sock`. I've verified the socket works outside of the code using `ssh -S /tmp/ubuntu.sock -fNT x`.

If you've ever used a master control socket to go interactive on a system, then you know you have to pass some character after the socket. In my case, I pass `x`. I'm wondering if I need to do something similar within my code? If I don't pass that `x` in, I will not get a shell prompt. That said, I'm not trying to go interactive in my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko 
from paramiko import Transport
import socket
import time
import logging
import sys
import re
import os
import argparse

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

#DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL = logging.ERROR # Default log level

class RemoteConnect:
 
    def __init__(self, ip, hostname, username, password, port, socket_path=None):
        self.ip = ip
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.port = port 
        self._socket = None
        self.Transport = None
        self.chan = None
        self.sudo_chan = None
        self.sudo_authenticated = False
        self.cmd_friendly_name = None
        self.output_dir = "/work/hosts/{}-{}".format(self.hostname, self.ip)
        os.makedirs(self.output_dir, exist_ok=True)
        self.socket_path = socket_path
        self.__connect()


    def __connect(self):
        try:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.load_system_host_keys()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

            if self.socket_path and os.path.exists(self.socket_path):
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.connect(self.socket_path)

                # Create a new Transport object using the socket
                t = Transport(sock) # type: ignore
                print("Transport object created")
                t.start_client(timeout=10)
                print("Transport started")

                # Authenticate using the username and password
                t.auth_password(username=self.username, password=self.password)

                # Open session and invoke a shell
                self.chan = t.open_session()
                self.chan.invoke_shell()

            else:
                # Connect using the TCP socket
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.connect((self.ip, int(self.port)))

                # Create a new Transport object using the socket
                t = paramiko.Transport(sock)
                t.start_client()

                # Authenticate using the username and password
                t.auth_password(username=self.username, password=self.password)

                # Open session and invoke a shell
                self.chan = t.open_session()
                self.chan.invoke_shell()

                self.ssh = ssh
                self.transport = t

        except paramiko.BadAuthenticationType:
            sys.stdout.write('Bad Password!\n')     
            sys.exit()
        except (paramiko.SSHException):
            sys.stdout.write('Connection Failed!\n')
            sys.exit()
        except (socket.error):
            sys.stdout.write('Failed to open socket\n')
            sys.exit()


    '''
    Need to figure out how to create a disconnect method. The one below does not work. 
    '''
    def close(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'channel'):
            self.chan.close() # type: ignore
        self.transport.close()
        self.ssh.close()


    def exec_command(self, cmd, cmd_friendly_name):
        # create a logger object
        logger = logging.getLogger("ssh_client")
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create a file handler and set the logging level
        fh = logging.FileHandler("ssh_client.log")
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create a logging format and set it for the handler
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        # add the handler to the logger
        logger.addHandler(fh)

        for command in cmd:
            logger.info("CMD= " + command + "\n")
    
            # Send the command
            self.chan.send(command + "\n") # type: ignore
            
            # Clear the receive buffer
            receive_buffer = b""
        
            timeout = time.time() + 2 # Set a timeout of 5 seconds
            while not self.chan.exit_status_ready(): # Wait for the command to finish # type: ignore
                if self.chan.recv_ready(): # Check if there is data to receive # type: ignore
                    receive_buffer += self.chan.recv(4096) # type: ignore
                    output = receive_buffer.decode("utf-8")
                    self.print_output(command, output)
                    self.write_output(cmd_friendly_name, output)
                    timeout = time.time() + 2 # Reset the timeout if we receive data
                elif time.time() > timeout:
                    logger.error("Timeout reached")
                    break
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)

    
    def authenticate_sudo(self):
        """
        Authenticates the user as sudo and stores the authentication state in a class variable.
        """
        # Check if we are already authenticated as sudo
        if self.sudo_authenticated:
            print("Already authenticated as sudo")
            return
            
        # Send the sudo command with the user's password
        self.chan.send(f"echo '{self.password}' | sudo -S -s sh\n") # type: ignore
        
        # Wait for the authentication result
        receive_buffer = b""
        timeout = time.time() + 40 # Set a timeout of 10 seconds
        while not receive_buffer.endswith(b"\n"):
            if self.chan.recv_ready(): # Check if there is data to receive  # type: ignore
                receive_buffer += self.chan.recv(1024) # type: ignore
                timeout = time.time() + 5 # Reset the timeout if we receive data
            elif time.time() > timeout:
                print("Timeout reached while waiting for authentication result")
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        
        # Store the authentication state and channel
        if receive_buffer.strip() == b"assword:": # Password prompt received
            print("Failed to authenticate as sudo")
            self.sudo_authenticated = False
            self.sudo_chan = None
        else: # Authentication successful
            self.sudo_authenticated = True
            self.sudo_chan = self.chan
            print("Successfully authenticated as sudo")
    

    def exec_sudo_command(self, commands, cmd_friendly_name):
        
        """
        Executes a command as sudo and returns the command output.
        """
        if not self.sudo_authenticated:
            print("Error: not authenticated as sudo")
            return None

        for cmd in commands:
            
            # Send the command
            self.sudo_chan.send(f"sudo {cmd}\n") # type: ignore
            
            # Clear the receive buffer
            receive_buffer = b""

            timeout = time.perf_counter() + 5 # Set a timeout of 30 seconds
            while not self.sudo_chan.exit_status_ready(): # Wait for the command to finish # type: ignore
                if self.sudo_chan.recv_ready(): # Check if there is data to receive # type: ignore
                    receive_buffer += self.sudo_chan.recv(4096) # type: ignore
                    output = receive_buffer.decode("utf-8")
                    self.print_output(cmd, output)
                    self.write_output(cmd_friendly_name, output)
                    timeout = time.perf_counter() + 3 # Reset the timeout if we receive data
                elif time.perf_counter() > timeout:
                    break
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.5)


    def print_output(self, cmd, output):
        """
        Prints the sudo command output, removing any control characters and extra whitespace.
        """
        output = re.sub(r"\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]", "", output) # Remove any control characters
        #output = output.strip() # Remove any leading/trailing whitespace
        if output:
            print("--------------------------------------------------")
            print(f"Output for command: \"{cmd}\"")
            print(output)

    def write_output(self, cmd_friendly_name, output):
        output_file = os.path.join(self.output_dir, f"{cmd_friendly_name}.survey")
        with open(output_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write("----------------------------------------\n")
            f.write(output + "\n")
            

if __name__=="__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Completes a non-interactive SSH connection to a remote host and executes a series of commands for survey purposes.")
    parser.add_argument("--ip", '-i',type=str, help="IP address of the remote host")
    parser.add_argument("--hostname", '-n',type=str, help="Hostname of the remote host")
    parser.add_argument("--username", '-u',type=str, help="Username for the remote host")
    parser.add_argument("--password", '-s',type=str, help="Password for the remote host")
    parser.add_argument("--port", '-p', type=str, help="Port for the remote host")
    parser.add_argument("--socket_path", '-k', type=str, help="Socket for the remote host")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    x = RemoteConnect(args.ip, args.hostname, args.username, args.password, args.port, args.socket_path)
    x.authenticate_sudo()
    x.exec_sudo_command(["/bin/cat /etc/shadow", "/bin/cat /etc/passwd", "/bin/cat /etc/group"],"sudo_commands")
    x.exec_sudo_command(["/bin/ps -auxHwxx"],"ps")
    x.exec_command(["/sbin/ip a", ],"network")
    x.exec_command(["/sbin/ip neighbor"],"neighbors")
    x.exec_command(["/usr/bin/w", "/usr/bin/last", "/usr/bin/lastlog"],"logged_in")
    x.close()
```